# Why is the mustache of my model's image texture missing in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, eevee-render-engine, lighting

The mustache does not show in cycles at any exposure or color management setting. Displacement and bump maps of the greyscale image texture do not help at all. Bump mapping just adds a bunch of polygonal-looking dark spots all over the mesh, while displacement does nothing. Comparing cycles to Eevee, the original model looks like a different person as the eyebrows are unrealistically desaturated, the mustache is nowhere to be seen, and the skin on the face is mostly one shade of white.

The model was created by UV mapping two images of a person on the stock man mesh that was provided by a blender 3.6 package. Additional non-quad destroying sculpting was done in Eevee to get the head to match the image texture. I did it in Eevee because my computer isn't good enough to sculpt in cycles.

[image: Eevee viewport view of model (man)]

[image: Cycles viewport view of model (man)]

[image: Wireframe of model (man)]

Comment: Without seeing material node tree or your file really hard to tell ... Could be too strong subsurfscattering (SSS) ... Or many other things 

Comment: @vklidu Subsurface Scattering is not the problem. It almost unnoticeably changes the look in cycles. I did not add the material node tree as an image attachment because it's just a UV map node connected to an image texture connected to the principal BSDF base color node. I tweaked every setting on the BSDF node, and nothing helped.

Comment: Now you wasted 6 our (or more) your comment doesn't give as deeper insight ... share your simplified file with image packed in blend file (since you need to solve just the mustang you can delete all other parts of body and keep just a lower part of head. To share file use https://blend-exchange.com

Answer (score 0):

Subdivision Surface was blurring out the details of textures in cycles, and I can't explain why unfortunately. You need subdivision surface at extremely low values to preserve detail unlike Eevee. In this question, I was working in blender version 3.6 and 3.6.1.